# Is this question an exact duplicate or just similar?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, specific-question

I was having a [discussion with another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43487811/what-is-python-dot-dot-notation-syntax#comment74076738_43487811) regarding if a question of [mine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43487811/6622817) should be closed as an *exact* duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31037609/why-is-1-real-a-syntax-error-but-1-real-valid-in-python). I believe they are different in their own ways and that they are similar but *not exactly the same*. He recommended to ask the community for opinions on the meta site and here I am.

Comment: Your question is closed as a *duplicate*, not an *exact duplicate*.  The questions don't need to be *exactly* the same, the difference simply don't need to be relevant to the answers.

Comment: Don't the two duplicates fully answer the question? If they do then it's completely valid to close it, otherwise you could edit your question to include what information those answers are lacking for your particular question.

Comment: I think both of those dupe sufficiently answer your question.  They have a lot of extra detail but I kinda like that as you learn more (\o/)

Comment: Hi, firstly, let me say thanks for posting this on meta, it's one way to get this resolved as objectively as possible :-). Secondly, I still stand behind  my opinion that the question is a dupe, I think the others sufficiently answer yours, I'll see if I find time to post an answer here explaining why.

Comment: If literally being exactly the same was the requirement for duplicates, nothing would ever be closed. You stated that the linked posts answered your question. The way duplicates work, different well asked questions that have the exact same answer are *good*, they add more search terms to funnel searchers to one canonical place. You seem to think a duplicate is a bad thing; it is not.

Comment: Remember that it's not closed as dupe, it's marked as dupe. Being a dupe is OK :)

Comment: I think what you're explicitly asking doesn't really matter since the mechanism for marking a question as an "exact duplicate" and the mechanism for making a question as "this question already has an answer here" (e.g. dupe but not exact dupe) is the same.

Comment: In the case of what you seem to mean with your question, it seems pretty clear to me that the older question is a specific case that should be closed as a dupe of your more canonical, newer question.

Comment: those questions dont even look slightly related

Comment: I think some people on Stack Overflow are far too quick to mark questions as duplicates. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43153206/spring-social-authorizationexception-with-facebook) is another example. I came across this when trying to solve a problem. The supposed dupe was no help whatsoever. I spent many hours figuring the problem out myself. When I had done so, I posted another question with an answer describing what I had found out.

Comment: Please find the paper: [Same-Same But Different: On Understanding Duplicates in Stack Overflow](https://link.springer.com/epdf/10.1007/s00287-019-01185-y?author_access_token=4ng7vOyh-yU7oLfVMagsyPe4RwlQNchNByi7wbcMAY5lCJNKFDYMtTI1hi-UDreOlx6HXVj5d3jqkTNMMUis5IQZLnj3CdxWAbc9nNVcjY0BGmm0Gl8tPv1PgHKVXWZRbCLObWStK8UN9aBUoENEoA%3D%3D) that might answer your question whether it is an exact or a similar duplicate in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 19):

I'm not seeing it as a dupe of either of those questions, honestly.  The main contention point with your question is that you're trying to figure out if `..` is actually syntax, when it isn't.  More importantly, the top-rated answer on your question actually succinctly *answers your question well*.

It's up to the community to decide this ultimately, but I'm not seeing this as a dupe, and I've voted accordingly.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I'm concerned, the questions are not even that similar. It so happens that they arise due to the same underlying phenomenon, but unless you *already know* the common underlying cause, it would be very unlikely for you to recognize the two questions as related. One is definitely not a rephrasing of the other.

There is an [instructive answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/153413) to a question on Meta regarding duplicates, which includes this passage:

> Questions asking about the same aspect of the same concept, but with different examples, may or may not be considered duplicates. It depends how easy it is to figure out one example from the other. If it's only a matter of changing some numerical values or some variable names, they're duplicates. If understanding why the questions are at all related requires a detailed explanation, the questions aren't duplicates, merely related.

I think the last sentence clearly describes the situation here. The questions are related, but not duplicates.

Answer (score 6):

You specifically stated in a comment that the answers to the duplicate questions answers the question asked, so yes, they are absolutely duplicates.  That there are differences in the question that don't change the fact that the other answers answer your question doesn't make them not duplicates.

Comment: "You specifically stated in a comment that the answers to the duplicate questions answers the question asked, so yes, they are absolutely duplicates." This in itself may not prove it to be a duplicate; you could in theory have wildly different questions with the same answer

Comment: @Orangesandlemons If the quesitons are *wildly* different, then they're *not* going to have the same answer.  This is precisely why the "duplicate" guidelines and close message says, "is answered by the other question" rather than, "is a duplicate question".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142855/discussion-on-answer-by-servy-is-this-question-an-exact-duplicate-or-just-simila).

Answer (score -3):

Please find my paper: [Same-Same But Different: On Understanding Duplicates in Stack Overflow](http://em.rdcu.be/wf/click?upn=lMZy1lernSJ7apc5DgYM8fzDkprixZ1FNk6fiwA9k20-3D_77ujxPxaQ3dycljn6VGozoSDsMPjbcLHDYXiK7o6VlAkJ8kDIXBmNAcx7EhbzRsG1TAXQ7QvcSM8UsQJZHeAmsRmopz5vjIjEhkzoKOT37doRo44oOS5v8S725fA-2F6qiEXRbMr87eCD-2B7Y7DFEJD8YppWoSxeBjfkb4Sk54FnhvolDIvygSWbmjFCiQVhF4AmeiLoN24Fc3dmj7JGVzCCLdPcjtSfYM1HV615vZocp5lIQlGzZXmdHxGtgs1I6kypmb3P7I9LC0-2BgDWEXacbweAAeHdP7gcbsYpXIh1hjsE-3D) that might answer your question whether it is an exact or a similar duplicate in Stack Overflow. The publisher said (Springer Nature): "There are no restrictions on the number of people you may share this link with, how many times they can view the linked article or where you can post the link online" so enjoy the paper!

Comment: It looks like you put a fair amount of work into that paper. It's too bad it is not reflected in this answer.

Comment: Well, this is better than [the comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348183/is-this-question-an-exact-duplicate-or-just-similar/391043#comment738863_348183), which did not announce your affiliation with the paper and thus could be considered spam according to the rules of the site.