# Why was my moderator flag to have a duplicate question closed/reopened declined?

Tags: support, faq, duplicate-questions, declined-flags, moderation

I ran across a question that I believe is a duplicate (or was wrongly closed as a duplicate). I flagged it for moderator attention, but my flag was declined.

Why won't moderators do anything about this? How can I get this problem fixed?

[Return to FAQ index](/q/251225)

---

> **Moderator note:** This is for the purpose of creating a [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) entry, and is an attempt to cover multiple use cases moderators encounter in flag handling. The [prior question regarding this issue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291977) contains advice that is incomplete.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are a couple of reasons why moderators tend to decline requests to resolve duplicate-closure disputes:

### A) You [probably] haven't done the preliminary work

If you disagree with a particular question's duplicate target—whether it's your own question or not—the first thing you should do is to edit the question to explain why the proposed duplicate is not adequate, why the questions are different, and why the existing answers don't solve the problem being asked about.

In the vast majority of cases when moderator flags are raised on disputed duplicates, this critical step hasn't been taken, which prompts us to decline these flags with a message like:

> If you disagree that a question is a duplicate, you should edit the question to clarify the difference and why those answers didn't solve the problem. See: ["This question already has answers here" - but it does not. What can I do when I think a question is not a duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252252)

Note that taking this step doesn't *guarantee* that a moderator will indulge your flag, for the reasons described below. But it is an essential first step, which you should take whether or not a moderator is to be involved.

### B) Moderators are not subject-matter experts on all topics

Moderators are regular users who volunteer their time to help improve the site. While a moderator is expected to have lots of experience on the Stack Overflow network, there is no way for an individual moderator to be enough of a *technical* expert in all programming questions to competently resolve duplicate closure conflicts. Even when the entire team of moderators is considered, there is no guarantee that we have experts on every topic.

Once in a while, you might get lucky and have a dispute where a particular moderator has the technical competence to resolve it, but *you cannot guarantee a specific moderator will see a specific flag*. Requesting a specific moderator within your flag is not a viable solution either (as a moderator may be temporarily unavailable). It doesn't scale.

What this means if that if you raise a flag requesting a moderator to adjudicate a duplicate-closure dispute *on a technical basis*, it is likely to be declined.

If there is a blatant mistake in question closure that any non-expert can judge, or that a moderator can judge based solely on their familiarity with the Stack Exchange platform, then it is fine to flag those (just explain clearly why moderator intervention is necessary—see the next section).

### C) The community has tools to handle this without moderator intervention

[Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard), who was a moderator at the time, [made this point previously, in response to a similar Meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291978):

> [M]oderator flags should be used for things the community cannot handle on its own without moderator intervention. There's a reopen queue for exactly this situation. Moderators don't need to get involved.

There are several community tools for handling duplicate closure disputes:

1. [**Close and Reopen votes**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) (and their associated [**review queues**](https://stackoverflow.com/review)). If you have [enough reputation to flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts), you can flag a question for closure. There is no corresponding reopen flag, unfortunately, but once you have close-vote privileges, you can also cast reopen votes.
2. **Chat**. Many popular languages have [chat rooms](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/) where you can discuss your concerns with subject-matter experts. This may inspire others to join you in changing the status of a question. For example, [the Python room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) is willing to discuss re-opening, re-targeting, and otherwise improving duplicate questions related to Python.

   Be respectful, do not make demands or hurl insults, and follow the room rules. Furthermore, be aware that jumping into a chat room *just* to get a question closed/reopened is unlikely to go well (especially if the question and/or answer is your own).
3. **Meta**. This site you're on right now. There's an [Ask Question button](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (really it's a link, but *shh*). Ask why a question is closed or reopened. Believe it or not, the Meta community can, and does, [help resolve duplicate disputes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/348183). Enough open discussion here should help resolve the issue (or burn enough votes either way so it cannot be changed by those who disagree). It's not a clean process, but it works.

---

### Wait—so do moderators *ever* intervene in duplicate disputes?

We do, but usually because the process has broken down somewhere.

A question being closed and reopened over and over as a duplicate will raise an auto-flag for moderator attention. You should also flag abusive uses of gold badges (such as a gold badge holder who closes and reopens just to clear close votes, or [someone answering and then dupe-hammering a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/415621)).

It's important to note that in cases like this *we're not being asked to weigh in on if we think the duplicate status is warranted*. At that point, we're enforcing rules or stopping a question from being thrashed between two states (where we'd lock the question temporarily). In other words, this is a *system-level exception*, which is [precisely when moderators get involved](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators#:%7E:text=Moderators%20are%20human%20exception%20handlers,disrupt%20the%20community.).